# PHP script doesnt work in direct admin but work in cPanel

Tags: php, hosting, directadmin

guys i have a PHP Script and i install it on Direct admin and i got this error
i have try change php version but its dont work
but i install this script on other host but in cPanel and its work fine

`This page isn’t working avesk.net is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500`

I'm not a professional. Explain a little simple what to do
why ? anyone can help me?

Comment: Aside from PHP versions it might depend what is contained in the script. Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

In DirectAdmin
There are several possible causes for receiving 500 error.

- If you migrated your account from cPanel to DirectAdmin, check in public_html your .htacces file and remove everything that was created by cPanel, there is usually a comment before and after the code stating that this part was created by cPanel.
- PHP version. Try to use in DirectAdmin the same version of PHP(cPanel) if possible.

Log in to DirectAdmin (at the user level)

- If your server works with php-fpm, just below the domain name, there will be an option to change the PHP version of your account.
- If your server work with CloudLinux, find the "Extra Features" menu and then "Select PHP Version". In this case you can change the version of PHP you want to use, and enable / disable PHP extensions (often a disabled extension can cause error 500).

If you have root access to the server, it is very likely that you will find some information in the log.

tail /var/log/httpd/domains/yourdomain.com.error.log

===

Regards